# How much does it cost to add hardpoints to armor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

I am looking to add the stealth mod in the main book to armored clothing. The mod requires two hard points to be applied to any armor. Armored clothing only has one hard point. Is there any way to add (via credits) a hard point to armor? If so, how much would it typically cost?

The Gageteer gets a skill called Tinkerer that adds one hard point per rank of Tinkerer, but I don't have a Gageteer in my party, so I would have to find someone to do this for me. The tree only has one Tinkerer rank in it and it does not appear in another tree (to my knowledge). I am unsure if they are allowed to do this to items then sell them.

Comment: I don't think hiring someone else to add hardpoints to your equipment should work. It reflects the tinkerer constantly tinkering with his own gear. If someone else uses the gear, it'll soon break down, while the tinkerer is back to tinkering on something new.

Comment: Having a third party use the Tinker talent to add hard points to your armor *could* work, so long as you return to the third party for maintenance on a *very* regular schedule.  Miss your daily/weekly tuneup, whatever was using that hard point ceases to function, maybe even permanently (having to be replaced/rebuilt from the ground up).

Answer (score 4):

The number of hardpoints armour has is an inherent limitation—they simply physically do not have anywhere to put the mod, or lack sufficient internal power systems to make it function. No amount of credits can overcome that.

This makes sense for "armoured clothing," which is merely a set of plates you wear under bulky clothing. There isn't anywhere to attach a moderately-sized mod like the Optical Camouflage System, and it doesn't have a power or control system to make the OCS go.

This makes sense from a game-design perspective too—if more hardpoints could simply be added with more money, there would be no point in using the concept of hardpoints as a limitation and it would simply give an increased cost. Further, there'd then be nothing apart from money and XP (potentially unlimited, over a long enough game) to prevent people from attaching every single mod to their "stealthy" under-clothes plates.

---

To accomplish what you're aiming to using gear, you have two options. You can either:

- Wear heavier armour such as Laminate, which is designed to "be easily modified with after-market attachments" such as an OCS.
- Or you can somehow acquire an Outlaw Tech Personal Stealth Field. Good luck with that, though—they're Rarity 9 and cost 20,000 credits!

Comment: There is the Gageteer skill Tinkerer that allows you to add a Hard Point to an Item. So you can add 1 hard point with XP...

Comment: @Popo Aha, I missed that. If that solves your problem, it's OK here to answer your own question!

Comment: Not really, because I am not a Gageteer and you cant buy XP with Creds... I am just unsure if a Gageteer can do that to someone elses equipement permanantly. (will update question with that info)

Answer (score 4):

Hardpoints can not be bought per RAW, they are added via various talents in the game system.

The Outlaw Tech also has two ranks in Tinkerer.  Gageteer has one.  Since both Tinkerer talents in Outlaw Tech are at the 5 XP level, my suggestion would be to dip into that specialization and grab them.  You'd also be able to add 2 Hard Points to another item as well.

As a GM, I would let the PC buy them from NPCs for an extremely high price.  I usually allow my PCs to purchase services for skills they do not have (fixing ships, getting IDs made, etc) usually at a significant cost to them.

Comment: For more details on cost, see **Obligations**. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't Modify your armor with Cash. Hard points is a built in limitation. but there area  few ways to get the same end result.

First of all there are other armors that might suit your purpose. maybe the question is about swapping to a different armor. Check out the Mimetic Suit from Fly casual, the Second Skin Armor from Desperate Allies, and the Zephyr Stealth Suit from Endless Vigil.

Secondly, if playing with items is something you like, There are three talent Trees i know of that Grant the Tinkerer Enhancement. Consider picking up another tree, that will let you customize items for your own character. they only work for the character who has Tinkerer (they break down if they aren't being constantly maintained), but the three Talent Trees i know of, are Technician: Outlaw, Tech Technician: Modder (from Special Modifications) and Bounty Hunter: Gadgateer.

Lastly you can hunt down Unique items which certainly exist within the galaxy. there are rules for Crafting your own gear with high mechanics skills, NPCs who posses these skills might charge favors, or high prices for special customized gear, but if you ask around in character, i'm sure your GM will eventually point you in the direction of a talented inventor who can make customized items.

There is no reason why you can't have what you want, it just might take a little work, which will only make for a better story.

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time you can take the [tour] to find out more about the site. To me, this seems like a good answer overall. I'd maybe add a few references to some of the things you are mentioning (page numbers?) just to help people find them more easily.